# Rails 5 - Rake task to import data from CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

I am trying to upload data I have kept in xls to my rails db. I have tried several different tutorials to get this working and outline the problems Im getting stuck with on each of them below. I don't mind which method I ultimately use, I'm just running out of ideas for how to try to solve this problem with any of these methods.

**[Importing CSV files by RichonRails](https://richonrails.com/articles/importing-csv-files)**

model:

```
class Randd::Field < ApplicationRecord

    require 'csv'


  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do | row |
            randd_field_hash = row.to_hash
            randd_field = Randd::Field.where(id: randd_field_hash["id"])
            if randd_field.count == 1
                randd_field.first.update_attributes(randd_field_hash)
            else
                Randd::Fields.create!(randd_field_hash)
            # else
            # Randd::Field.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end


end
```

routes:

```
namespace :randd do
resources :fields do
      collection {post :import }#do
        # post :create
      end
end
```

Controller:

```
class Randd::FieldsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @randd_fields = Randd::Field.all
end

def new
    @field = Randd::Field.new
end

def create
    # @field = Randd::Field.new(randd_field_params)
    Randd::Field.create(params[:randd_field][:file])
    redirect_to action: "index", notice: "Data imported"
end

def show
    redirect_to action: "index"
end

def import
    Randd::Field.import(params[:file])
    # Randd::Field.create(params[:randd_field]['file'])
    redirect_to action: "index", notice: "Data imported"
end

private
 def randd_field_params
  params.fetch(:randd_field, {}).permit(:title, :anz_reference)
 end

end
```

When I save this and try it, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
```

The error message points at the import method in the model

**GoRails Tutorial**:

I tried to follow the GoRails tutorial for importing data from a csv file.

In my rails app, I have saved the file as for_codes.csv.

In my lib/tasks folder, I have made a file called: import.rake

In my input.rake file, I have:

```
require 'csv'
namespace :import do

  desc "import research fields from csv"
  task rannd_fields: :environment do
    filename = File.join Rails.root, 'for_codes.csv'
    counter = 0

    CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do | row |
      p row ["anz_reference"]
      for_code = Randd::Field.create(anz_reference: row["anz_reference"], title: title)
      counter += 1 if randd_field.persisted?
    end
    puts "Imported #{counter} field codes"
  end
end
```

When I then try this in the console, with:

```
bundle exec rake import:randd_fields
```

I get an error that says:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `randd_fields' for main:Object
```

The model I'm trying to make records on is called:

```
class Randd::Field < ApplicationRecord
```

The table in the database is called:

```
randd_fields
```

Can anyone see what I need to do to rake this task?

**BACKTRACE**

```
bundle exec rake import:rannd_fields
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
/Users/live/lib/tasks/import.rake:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => import:rannd_fields
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
MacBook-Pro:live em$ bundle exec rake import:rannd_fields --trace
** Invoke import:rannd_fields (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute import:rannd_fields
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:2016:in `=~'
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:2016:in `init_separators'
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1538:in `initialize'
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1273:in `new'
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1273:in `open'
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1130:in `foreach'
/Users/live/lib/tasks/import.rake:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => import:rannd_fields
```

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

I next tried making a brand new file in my rails app. I typed these three lines in:

anz_reference   | title
010104p | Combinatorics and Discrete Mathematics (excl. Physical Combinatorics)
010107p |   Mathematical Logic, Set Theory, Lattices and Universal Algebra

The first row are the headers. They match attributes on the Randd::Field model.

The next two rows are the content Im trying to import. The cell values are separated by the | (as shown in the GoRails video).

When I try this, I get the same error as I posted above:

$ bundle exec rake import:randd_fields --trace
    ** Invoke import:randd_fields (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment
    ** Execute import:randd_fields
    nil
    rake aborted!
    NameError: undefined local variable or method `title' for main:Object

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I have also tried this tutorial **[How to import CSV files in Rails by Matt Morgante](http://www.mattmorgante.com/technology/csv)** and tried to use the rails cast and the Roo gem to the same end. Neither of these options work - the Rails Cast is old, so probably out of date, and the comments in the post to the other tutorial show many others have not been able to get that approach to work - maybe things in Rails have changed since it was proposed.

It was suggested on the GoRails forum that the problem might be attributable to the CSV file is not encoded to the UTF-8 specifications. It was suggested that this might be overcome by transferring the data to a sheet in google drive and then downloading this as a csv for use with rails. I tried this.

I get the same error as I got when I ran the rake task with a file created in xls.

**ZHONG'S SUGGESTION**

Taking Zhong's suggestion, I tried changing the import.rake task to:

```
require 'csv'
namespace :import do

  desc "import research fields from csv"
  task randd_fields: :environment do
    filename = File.join Rails.root, 'for_codes.csv'
    counter = 0

    CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do | row |
      p row ["anz_reference"]
      # for_code = Randd::Field.create(anz_reference: row["anz_reference"], title: title)
      for_code = Randd::Field.create(anz_reference: row["anz_reference"], title: row['title'])
      counter += 1 if for_code.persisted?
    end
    puts "Imported #{counter} field codes"
  end
end
```

When I then try to

```
bundle exec rake import:randd_fields
```

I get the same error:

```
bundle exec rake import:randd_fields
NameError: undefined local variable or method `randd_fields' for main:Object
    from (irb):6
```

Comment: Try RanndField as the class name.

Comment: Where should I write that Tom?  Do you mean: for_code = RanddField.create in the import.rake file?

Comment: As your class name instead of Randd::Field

Comment: Hi Tom - no, that would not be correct. The resource Field is namespaced inside the Randd folder, so the model name is correct the way I have it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I see. Sorry. If you haven't gotten an answer I'll look at it tomorrow evening.

Comment: Thanks very much Tom

Comment: line and backtrace of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be two problems here.

1. Encoding in your csv file. `ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`
2. Undefined local variable. `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'randd_fields' for main:Object`

   I guess you are trying to count created/imported records:

   ```
   for_code = Randd::Field.create(anz_reference: row["anz_reference"], title: title)
   counter += 1 if randd_field.persisted?
   ```

   the record you created is `for_code`, however you are checking against `randd_field`.
   This should fix it

   ```
   counter +=1 if for_code.presisted?
   ```

**Updated:**

> $ bundle exec rake import:randd_fields --trace ** Invoke import:randd_fields (first_time) ** Invoke environment (first_time) ** Execute environment ** Execute import:randd_fields nil rake aborted! NameError: undefined local variable or method `title' for main:Object

this is because `title` variable is not defined. I guess you want to use `row[]` here.

```
for_code = Randd::Field.create(anz_reference: row["anz_reference"], title: row['title'])
```

**Updated 2:**

You have a typo in your rake task name

**Updated 3:**

I think you are calling `bundle exec rake import:randd_fields` inside rails console. 
Run it directly in terminal should fix it.

Comment: Hi Zhong, I tried to run the rake task again having made the change you suggested, but I get the same error as I got using the formulation suggested in the GoRails tutorial (which is what I set out in the post above).bundle exec rake import:randd_fields
NameError: undefined local variable or method `randd_fields' for main:Object
 from (irb):5

Comment: I guess you updated the rake task, because I can't find any `randd_fields` besides task name. Can you update the code snippet?  I've updated regarding the fix for `title` error.

Comment: I added the updated import.rake file to the end of the post above. I still get the same error

Comment: You have a typo. The one you are calling does not match the rake task name. Updated answer.

Comment: I tried again - with the task named randd_fields, but I still get: bundle exec rake import:randd_fields 
NameError: undefined local variable or method `randd_fields' for main:Object

Comment: I actually cant add trace to the bundle command: bundle exec rake import:randd_fields --trace
SyntaxError: (irb):5: syntax error, unexpected unary-, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
bundle exec rake import:randd_fields --trace
                                      ^

Comment: I think you are calling `bundle exec rake` in rails console. You should run it directly in terminal, and it should fix it.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: I have to wait for 19 hours to give the bounty

Comment: Glad it helped. :)